# How to select one column from class and transform it into list of Long

Tags: hibernate

I have a class named "Store" that maps to DB table named "STORE"

I would like to select a single column (Column name = "ID") from this table and return it as list of Long.

I tried this, but it's not working:

Criteria cr = dbs.createCriteria(Store.class)
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("id"), "id"))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Long.class));
return cr.list();

I think I know why it's not working, it's because "Long" is immutable and doesn't have a setter.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the type of `ID`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Criteria api is useful for dynamically generated queries, but too complex and leading to less readable and maintainable code for static queries. You should use HQL for such a simple static query:

```
String hql = "select store.id from Store store";
// now execute the query
```

If you persist in using Criteria, then the same query should be composed:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Store.class, "store");
c.setProjection(Projections.property("store.id"));
// now execute the query
```